# Is it true that for a Boolean Algebra, $a'b+(abc)'+c(b'+a)=b'+c'$?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, boolean-algebra

Analyze if the following statement is true or false: **Suppose $(D,+,\cdot,',0,1)$ is a Boolean Algebra. Then $a'b+(abc)'+c(b'+a)=b'+c'$.**

---

My guess is that the statement is **false**.

Let $D=D_{15}$ be the divisors of $15$. The Hasse diagram is

[image: Hasse diagram of D_{15}]

We know that $(D,+,\cdot,',0,1)$ is a Boolean Algebra since, by a property, $15$ can be expressed as a product of unique primes. So let for example $a=1$, $b=3$ and $c=15$. Then $a'=15$, $b'=5$ and $c'=1$, thus \begin{align*}a'b+(abc)'+c(b'+a)&=15\cdot3+(1\cdot3\cdot15)'+15\cdot(5+1)\\&=3+15+5\\&=15,\end{align*} but \begin{align*}b'+c'&=5+1\\&=5,\end{align*} hence the proposition is false.

---

Another way that occurred to me to prove that the proposition is false is through the truth tables of each expression, knowing that $\cdot$ represents the $\mathrm{AND}$ logical and $+$ is the $\mathrm{OR}$ logical. So:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline a&b&c&a'&b'&c'&a'b&abc&(abc)'&b'+a&c(b'+a)&a'b+(abc)'+c(b'+a)\\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T\\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T\\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T\\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T\\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T\\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T \\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T \\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T \\\hline
\end{array}$$
but
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline b&c&b'&c'&b'+c' \\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm F \\\hline
\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T \\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm F&\mathrm T \\\hline
\mathrm F&\mathrm F&\mathrm T&\mathrm T&\mathrm T \\\hline
\end{array}$$
As we can see, both truth tables do not produce the same truth values, hence the proposition is false.

**Are both options correct to prove that each one separately proves the falsehood of the proposition?**

Thanks!!

Comment: Your decision is right, the table is correct.

Comment: @user376343 thank you!! Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Besides the methods you used, there are various other.

Karnaugh map is full of 1s.

BA rules applied to the LHS give 
$$\begin{aligned} a'b+(abc)'+c(b'+a)&=a'b+ a'+b'+c'+cb'+ca\\&=(a'b+ a')+(b'+cb')+c'+ac\\ &=a'+b'+c'+ac\\ &=(a'+a)(a'+c)+b'+c'\\ &=a'+c+b'+c'=1\end{aligned}$$ which is clearly not equal to RHS.